# How to convert bbcode to html in usage of SCEditor

Tags: php, editor, bbcode, php-parser

I used [SCEditor](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor) in my forum. I managed inserting bbcodes to database. But when I try to show codes in the page, bbcodes are shown without styling. No html, no style. Only bad bbcodes. I am investigating for a long time in its documentation pages but I did not find any php parser. Here is the screenshot. [image] Please, could you help me, how do I parse bbcode to html in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SBBCodeParser](http://www.samclarke.com/2011/09/sbbcodeparser-php-bbcode-parser-class/). SCEditor and this class were coded by the same person. So it would be more compatible.